# PyQt5 QTableWidget GUI update is too slow when there are many cells

Tags: pyqt5, qthread, qtablewidget

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.mdi.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.mdi.setOption(QMdiArea.DontMaximizeSubWindowOnActivation)
        self.mdi.setViewMode(QMdiArea.TabbedView)
        self.mdi.setTabPosition(QTabWidget.South)
        self.mdi.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.mdi.setTabsMovable(True)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)

        self.bar = self.menuBar()

        self.file = self.bar.addMenu("File")
        self.file.addAction("New")
        self.file.addAction("cascade")
        self.file.addAction("Tiled")
        self.file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)

        self.action2 = QAction("Plus1(GUI update Main Thread)")
        self.bar.addAction(self.action2)
        self.action2.triggered.connect(self.plus)

        self.action3 = QAction("Plus2(Thread Communication with Signal&Slot")
        self.bar.addAction(self.action3)
        self.action3.triggered.connect(self.plus2)

        self.action4 = QAction("Plus3(GUI update in Thread")
        self.bar.addAction(self.action4)
        self.action4.triggered.connect(self.plus3)

        self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

        self.show()

    def plus(self):
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.timeout)
        self.timer.start()

    def plus2(self):
        self.timer2 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer2.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer2.timeout.connect(self.timeout2)
        self.timer2.start()

    def plus3(self):
        self.timer3 = QTimer(self)
        self.timer3.setInterval(10)
        self.timer3.timeout.connect(self.timeout3)
        self.timer3.start()

    def timeout(self):
        for i in range(self.rows):
            item = self.tblWgt.item(i, 0)
            item.setText(str(item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole) + 1) + "%")
            item.setData(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole, item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole) + 1)

    def timeout2(self):
        self.r = Thread(self)
        self.r.updater.connect(self.updater)
        self.r.start()

    def timeout3(self):
        self.r2 = Thread2(self)
        self.r2.start()

    def updater(self, text, num, idx):
        item = self.tblWgt.item(idx, 0)
        item.setText(text)
        item.setData(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole, num)

    def windowaction(self, q):
        print("triggered")

        if q.text() == "New":
            self.tblWgt = QTableWidget()
            self.tblWgt.setSortingEnabled(True)

            self.tblWgt.setFocusPolicy(Qt.FocusPolicy.NoFocus)
            self.tblWgt.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)

            self.tblWgt.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Interactive)
            self.tblWgt.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

            self.rows = 300
            self.columns = 10
            self.tblWgt.setRowCount(self.rows)
            self.tblWgt.setColumnCount(self.columns)

            columnList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"]

            for i, column in enumerate(columnList):
                self.tblWgt.setHorizontalHeaderItem(i, QTableWidgetItem(column))

            for i in range(self.rows):
                item = NumericItem()
                item.setFlags(Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsEnabled)
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
                item.setForeground(QColor(0, 0, 255))
                item.setText(str(i + 1 - 10) + "%")
                item.setData(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole, i + 1 - 10)
                self.tblWgt.setItem(i, 0, item)

            self.sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            self.sub.setWidget(self.tblWgt)

            self.sub.setGeometry(0, 0,
                             self.tblWgt.horizontalHeader().length() + self.tblWgt.verticalHeader().width() + self.tblWgt.contentsMargins().left() + self.tblWgt.contentsMargins().right() + 8 * 2 + 17
                             , 1000)  # self.tblWgt.verticalHeader().length() + self.tblWgt.horizontalHeader().height() + self.tblWgt.contentsMargins().top() + self.tblWgt.contentsMargins().bottom() + QStyle.PM_TitleBarHeight + 1 + 8)

            self.sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow" + str(self.count))
            self.count = self.count + 1
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.sub)
            self.sub.show()

        if q.text() == "cascade":
            self.mdi.cascadeSubWindows()

        if q.text() == "Tiled":
            self.mdi.tileSubWindows()


class Thread(QThread):
    updater = pyqtSignal(str, int, int)

    def __init__(self, app):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.app = app

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.app.rows):
            item = self.app.tblWgt.item(i, 0)
            self.updater.emit(str(item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole) + 1) + "%", item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole) + 1, i)


class Thread2(QThread):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(Thread2, self).__init__()
        self.app = app

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.app.rows):
            item = self.app.tblWgt.item(i, 0)
            item.setText(str(item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole) + 1) + "%")
            item.setData(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole, item.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.UserRole) + 1)


class NumericItem(QTableWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.data(Qt.UserRole) < other.data(Qt.UserRole)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    app.exec_()
```

I uploaded the full source, so please test it as it is.

Updating GUI on the main thread is of course slow.(Plus1 Button)
So, I used the way of updating GUI through the signal slot after working through the thread, but this is also still slow.(Plus2 Button)
If I update GUI in a thread, the internal value changes, but GUI does not change unless an event such as resize occurs and this way is not thread-safe..(Plus3 Button)
Then, how can data of many cells be updated in real time?

Comment: UI elements are **not** thread-safe, you should *never* access them from external threads. You **must** use signals for that, so I strongly suggest you to do some research on the topic as there are literally dozens of posts on the topic. Besides, QTableWidget is a high-level class (thus, easy to use, but also less performant), consider using a QAbstractTableModel subclass instead.

Comment: Since I am a foreigner, I have not been able to solve it no matter how many days I research. Do you have an example source? At first I used QAbstractTableModel, but it was very inefficient for my program, so I changed it to QTableWidget.

Comment: There are only cases similar to the above, but there is no solution to this case. As you can see from the source, it's not just about UI changes. The point is to stop on real-time updates.

Comment: For starters, unset the resize mode of the vertical header and set it only when you finished adding items *and* updating them. The `ResizeToContents` updates the whole view every time an item has changed: `self.tblWgt.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Fixed)` `self.tblWgt.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)`.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I have a few more questions.
1. If it is updated every 0.001s like setInterval(1) (there is no time to complete update. constantly update.), is it best to give a fixed size and not use the resizing mode?
2. Sorting by clicking on the header, drag slow down(and It looks like it's not 0.001s). Is there nothing I can do about it?
My program has this code: self.tblWgt.sortItems(self.tblWgt.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorSection(), self.tblWgt.horizontalHeader().sortIndicatorOrder()
to update the ranking in real time. Should I do like lowering this period to 1 second?

Comment: 3. Since UI elements are not thread-safe, then, of course, value update is not allowed, but shouldn't it also be read?
4. The program sometimes forcibly terminated even if the thread does not access the ui element and works with the signal slot. (Thread's run method just modified as follows:
data[i] += 1
self.updater.emit(str(data[i]) + "%", data[i], i)
)
Is this a multithreading issue?

I've asked several people, but I've been struggling with this seemingly simple problem for months. Please..

Comment: 1a. updating at each ms is quite pointless, you should use some batch mode and update at bigger regular intervals; 1b. the default resize mode for headers is `Fixed`, and `ResizeToContents` is increasingly slow with the amount of items; 2. sorting with hundreds of items is slow, you *might* have better results with a QTableView, a QAbstractItemModel (or QStandardItemModel) and QSortFilterProxyModel (but I'm not sure, test it on your own); obviously, increasing the number of items will make sorting even slower so you should do it at bigger intervals, but a custom model might be better ->

Comment: -> as long as the new items are added with a *good* implementation, so that you can sort items before updating the actual model; obviously, this is valid only for programmatical sorting, if you still need user sorting, QSortFilterProxyModel is still better; 3+4. I'm not sure what is the exact problem there, but it might be related to the fact that you're still accessing the UI at an arbitrary moment of *another* thread; and, no, it might seem a simple problem to you, but it's not :-)

Comment: In my program, it is necessary to update the screen every time when event is received. I really appreciate your help. I will try.